# Error when using react context - Cannot destructure property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

i trying to using Context on my react app
but i got error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'selected' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
```

in my InputsList file
on this line:

```
const { selected, setSelected } = useContext(ParamsContext);
```

ParamsContext:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const ParamsContext = createContext({
    selected: [],
    setSelected: () => {},
    textName: null,
    valueName: null
});
```

InputParams:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import InputsList from './InputsList';
    import { ParamsContext } from './services/ParamsContext';
    
    function InputParams(props) {
        const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
        const textName = "test";
        const valueName = "test2";
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                <ParamsContext.Provider
                    selected={selected}
                    setSelected={setSelected}
                    textName={textName}
                    valueName={valueName}>
                    <InputsList />
                </ParamsContext.Provider>
            </div>
        );
    }
    export default InputParams;
```

InputsList:

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { ParamsContext } from './services/ParamsContext';
    
    function InputsList(props) {
        const { selected, setSelected } = useContext(ParamsContext);
        return (
            <div>
                {selected.length}
            </div>
        );
    }

export default InputsList;
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contexte.Provider accept a `value` props,
And should be used like:

```
<ParamsContext.Provider value={{selected, setSelected, textName, valueName}}>
<\ParamsContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

Provider accept a value prop, in your case, an object. So it should be:

```
<ParamsContext.Provider
  value={{
     selected,
     setSelected,
     textName,
     valueName
  }}
>
   <InputsList />
</ParamsContext.Provider>
```

[See docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)